# kubernetes assign configmap as environment variables on deployment

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, configmap

I am trying to deploy my image to Azure Kubernetes Service. I use command:

```
kubectl apply -f mydeployment.yml
```

And here is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-api
        image: mycr.azurecr.io/my-api
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: my-existing-config-map
```

I have configmap `my-existing-config-map` created with a bunch of values in it but the deployment doesn't add these values as environment variables.

Config map was created from ".env" file this way:

```
kubectl create configmap my-existing-config-map --from-file=.env
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the content of my-exiting-config-map?

Comment: Also, how can you tell the environment variables aren't getting set?

Comment: @ChayneP.S. please see the updated question. The .env file is a simple file with Key=Value pairs

Comment: @DavidMaze I check pod logs and see that the application doesn't pick up env variables. It can only be because they were not set I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your .env file in this format

```
a=b
c=d
```

you need to use --from-**env**-file=.env instead.

To be more explanatory, using --from-file=aa.xx creates configmap looks like this

```
aa.xx: |
  file content here....
  ....
  ....
```

When the config map used with envFrom.configmapref, it just creates on env variable "aa.xx" with the content. In the case, that filename starts with '.' like .env , the env variable is not even created because the name violates UNIX env variable name rules.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the .env file the format of the file is important

1. Create config.env file in the following format which can include comments

```js
 echo -e "var1=val1\n# this is a comment\n\nvar2=val2\n#anothercomment" > config.env
```

2. Create Config Map

```js
kubectl create cm config --from-env-file=config.env
```

3. Use config Map in your pod definition file

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
labels:
    run: nginx
name: nginx
spec:
containers:
- image: nginx
    name: nginx
    resources: {}
    envFrom: 
    - configMapRef: 
        name: config
```